gRPC request aborted when sending large request
We have three services: an API, an orchestrator and finally an order service.
A REST request is sent to the API, it then calls the orchestrator service with gRPC, and the orchestrator calls several other services, including order, using gRPC.
The method that calls the order service takes a long time to respond (usually an hour or more). Until now, the service was working properly and there were no problems.
Since we added an interceptor, after 10 to 15 minutes, we get an error

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (104): Connection reset by peer.

While the order service is still doing its work, the connection has been disconnected:


Can you help me understand what causes this error?
We're using:

.NET 6
gRPC
Docker compose on linux ubuntu

